# Refresh MVVM architecture data

Tags: android, mvvm

I have a MVVM implementation to fetch data from internet using Retrofit2, Rxjava and Rxandroid.

My goal is to refresh the data when the user Swipes in the `SwipeRefreshLayout`. This is the implementation.

**NewsFeedFragment.java**

```
@Inject
ViewModelFactory viewModelFactory;
RandomVideosViewModel viewModel;


@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    ((BaseApplication) context.getApplicationContext())
            .getAppComponent()
            .inject(this);
    super.onAttach(context);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ... 

    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(RandomVideosViewModel.class);

    VideoCardAdapter videoCardAdapter = new VideoCardAdapter(getActivity());

    viewModel.videosList.observe(this, videoCardAdapter::submitList);
    viewModel.networkState.observe(this, videoCardAdapter::setNetworkState);

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(videoCardAdapter);

    ...
}
```

**RandomVideosViewModel.java**

```
public class RandomVideosViewModel extends ViewModel {

    public LiveData<PagedList<Video>> videosList;
    public LiveData<NetworkState> networkState;

    public RandomVideosViewModel(RandomVideosDataSourceFactory randomVideosDataSourceFactory) {

        networkState = Transformations.switchMap(randomVideosDataSourceFactory.getMutableLiveData(),
                PageKeyedRandomVideosDataSource::getNetworkState);

        PagedList.Config pagedListConfig = (new PagedList.Config.Builder()
                .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
                .setInitialLoadSizeHint(10)
                .setPageSize(10))
                .build();

        videosList = (new LivePagedListBuilder(randomVideosDataSourceFactory, pagedListConfig)).build();
    }

}
```

**RandomVideosDataSourceFactory**

```
public class RandomVideosDataSourceFactory extends DataSource.Factory {

    private MutableLiveData<PageKeyedRandomVideosDataSource> mutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
    private PageKeyedRandomVideosDataSource pageKeyedRandomVideosDataSource;

    public RandomVideosDataSourceFactory(PageKeyedRandomVideosDataSource pageKeyedRandomVideosDataSource) {
        this.pageKeyedRandomVideosDataSource = pageKeyedRandomVideosDataSource;
    }

    public MutableLiveData<PageKeyedRandomVideosDataSource> getMutableLiveData() {
        return mutableLiveData;
    }

    @Override
    public DataSource create() {
        mutableLiveData.postValue(pageKeyedRandomVideosDataSource);
        return pageKeyedRandomVideosDataSource;
    }
}
```

**PageKeyedRandomVideosDataSource**

```
public class PageKeyedRandomVideosDataSource extends PageKeyedDataSource<Integer, Video> {

    private static final String TAG = "Refresh - PageKeyedRand";

    private CompositeDisposable disposable = new CompositeDisposable();
    private MutableLiveData<NetworkState> networkState = new MutableLiveData<>();
    private MutableLiveData<NetworkState> initialLoading = new MutableLiveData<>();
    private Repository repository;
    private Random random = new Random();
    private int firstPage;
    private List<Integer> usedNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
    private int numbOfTimes = 0;

    public PageKeyedRandomVideosDataSource(Repository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public MutableLiveData<NetworkState> getNetworkState() {
        return networkState;
    }

    public MutableLiveData<NetworkState> getInitialLoading() {
        return initialLoading;
    }

    @Override
    public void
    loadInitial(@NonNull LoadInitialParams<Integer> params, @NonNull LoadInitialCallback<Integer, Video> callback) {
        List<Video> videoList = new ArrayList<>();
        networkState.postValue(NetworkState.LOADING);
        initialLoading.postValue(NetworkState.LOADING);

        firstPage = getFirstPage();
        usedNumbers.add(firstPage);
        numbOfTimes++;

        Log.i(TAG, "loadInitial: Loading page: " + firstPage + " - Size: " + params.requestedLoadSize);

        disposable.add(RxHelper.getObservable(repository.getHomeVideosObservable(params.requestedLoadSize, firstPage))
                .subscribe(requestVideo -> {
                    if (requestVideo != null) {
                        int lastPage = requestVideo.getLastPage();
                        int nextPage = getRandomPage(lastPage);
                        Log.i(TAG, "loadInitial: NextPage: " + nextPage);

                        videoList.addAll(requestVideo.getVideoList());
                        callback.onResult(videoList, null, nextPage);
                        networkState.postValue(NetworkState.LOADED);
                        initialLoading.postValue(NetworkState.LOADED);
                    }
                }, throwable -> {
                    throwable.printStackTrace();
                    networkState.postValue(NetworkState.failed(throwable.getMessage()));
                    initialLoading.postValue(NetworkState.failed(throwable.getMessage()));
                }));
    }

    @Override
    public void loadBefore(@NonNull LoadParams<Integer> params, @NonNull LoadCallback<Integer, Video> callback) {

    }

    @Override
    public void loadAfter(@NonNull LoadParams<Integer> params, @NonNull LoadCallback<Integer, Video> callback) {
        Log.i(TAG, "loadAfter: Loading page: " + params.key + " - Size: " + params.requestedLoadSize);
        List<Video> videoList = new ArrayList<>();
        networkState.postValue(NetworkState.LOADING);

        disposable.add(RxHelper.getObservable(repository.getHomeVideosObservable(params.requestedLoadSize, params.key))
                .subscribe(requestVideo -> {
                    if (requestVideo != null) {
                        int lastPage = requestVideo.getLastPage();
                        int nextPage = getRandomPage(lastPage);
                        Log.i(TAG, "loadAfter: NextPage: " + nextPage);

                        videoList.addAll(requestVideo.getVideoList());
                        callback.onResult(videoList, nextPage);
                        networkState.postValue(NetworkState.LOADED);
                    }
                }, throwable -> {
                    throwable.printStackTrace();
                    networkState.postValue(NetworkState.failed(throwable.getMessage()));
                }));
    }
```

The RandomVideosDataSourceFactory just retrieves the PageKeyedRandomVideosDataSource and this last one loads the data in chunk of pages.

**Question**

Once this data is loaded, I am not finding a way to refresh it when user uses the `SwipeRefreshLayout`. Any clue?

**What I tried**

I tried to recreate the ViewModel, but it seems it keeps retrieving the same instance.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, the best way is the abstract data collection from the ViewModel by placing it into a Repository.

The Repository is a singleton. It has a LiveData that the ViewModel observes.

The Repository gets the data initially from a cache (Room for example). It also observes that data.

When you need a new set of data (first load, swiping on refresh or even a Worker) you call your Repository to start updating the cache. That will automatically update the data in your ViewModel (and anything else that is observing the ViewModel).

Comment: Are u referring at [this example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/dev-todo-mvvm-live/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/tasks)? The problem is that I do not like a method in my repository that calls the api, it is loaded by the PageKeyedDataSource, at the first time I create the PakeKeyedDataSource it starts loading the data by chunk of pages and then I do not know how to call it again. I uploaded more code into the answer.

Comment: I edited my answer, I am using dagger2 to make the dependency injection. My ViewModel constructor receives the DataSourceFactory and the Factory receives the PageKeyed (which call the data). This is done once by dagger2, the only I imagine to make the call again is to recreate the PageKeyed.